# How to retrieve a value from a drag/dropped item and store in a form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

How can I add certain values to a form with Drag n Drop?

I would like to create a drag n drop list of groups that a user can choose to send information to. A user can drag and drop the group name to a certain area. After this operation, the form must know what `group_id` was added to the form (via hidden field for example).

How can I achieve this in an easy way? I would like to use jQuery to do this. FYI, I am using CodeIgniter and mySQL to process my forms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Sorry, but i cannot post my code. I was asking to get some theoretical replies with some example code (how you would do it i mean).

Comment: Thanks for your correction, but i found it a little bit offensive to correct my text without my permission.

Comment: Please familiarise yourself with the FAQ for this site before making that assumption.

Comment: Yeah, now i know. Sorry if that offended **you** ;)

Comment: No not at all, just making sure you understood how SO works :)